# Disable a field for input, without deleting it (to not lose old data)

Tags: entities

I have a field in my customer profile (shipping/billing, doesn't matter which).
I don't need this field anymore on checkout, but I want to keep the data of older orders.
(this can be extended to any entity type, it just happens that commerce customer profile is my use case)

Is it possible to somehow disable the field for input, but not really delete it?

Ideally with a UI solution.
I already know hook_form_alter() would do the trick..

Comment: hook_form_alter is what you want to use.  Set the #access attribute on that field to FALSE.

Comment: yes, just wondering if there is a more elegant / UI solution. I know that hook_form_alter() works, but I would not consider it an elegant solution. hook_form_alter() means hardcoded field name, and needs to target different forms. Conceptually what I want is not to alter a form, but to alter the status of the field itself.

Comment: So ifthere was a module that would provide a checkbox on the field configuration form, saying "this field is inactive" or "this is a legacy field, no more input", and then this module would do its dirtywork with hook_form_alter() or similar (maybe sth with field widget alter), this would already feel much better.

Comment: This said, I +1 your comment because I'm sure that the '#access' = FALSE is a piece of information that a number of people will be looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Field Permissions module](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to remove permissions for users to access the field.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, field permissions is an option. Maybe too heavy, maybe there is a more light-weight solution. But definitely counts as a legitimate answer. And maybe it is the only option currently available.